# boost local_date_time CET to UTC

Tags: c++, boost, timezone

I try to convert a boost `local_date_time` to UTC but I'm confused about the returned time of utc_time(). Here is a simplified code :

```
#include "boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp"

int main()
{
  using namespace boost::gregorian;
  using namespace boost::local_time;
  using namespace boost::posix_time;

  ptime dt = ptime(date(2015, Mar, 2), hours(0));
  time_zone_ptr tz_cet(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("CET"));
  local_date_time local_dt = boost::local_time::local_date_time(dt, tz_cet);

  std::cout << local_dt << std::endl;
  std::cout << local_dt.utc_time() << std::endl;

  time_zone_ptr tz_utc(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("UTC"));
  std::cout << local_dt.local_time_in(tz_utc) << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
2015-Mar-02 00:00:00 CET
2015-Mar-02 00:00:00
2015-Mar-02 00:00:00 UTC
```

UTC should be 1 hour behind CET (Central European Time).

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to do a bit more.  [Here is a Boost example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.local_utc_conversion) that I have used in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("CET")` constructor call creates a zone with the `CET` abbreviation and missing information about offset from UTC, time shift for DST, etc, i.e. the calls `boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("CET")` and `boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("UTC")` are different only in the TZ abbreviation names, the rest is the same. The [coliru code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd66afbdebe383a4) demonstrates it. The `base_utc_offset` method calls of the both TZs return `00:00:00`.

To fix the issue is necessary either to set time parameters of the `CET` zone, something like, "CET+01:00:00" or to use the [tz_database](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html#tz_database_intro) class to load the timezones from a CSV file.

The following code is the original modified code demonstrating how to fix the problem. Please note that the `CET` time zone description is not complete and provided only as an example.

```
#include "boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::gregorian;
    using namespace boost::local_time;
    using namespace boost::posix_time;

    ptime dt = ptime(date(2015, Mar, 2), hours(0));
    time_zone_ptr tz_cet(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("CET+01:00:00"));
    local_date_time local_dt = boost::local_time::local_date_time(dt, tz_cet);

    std::cout << local_dt << std::endl;
    std::cout << local_dt.utc_time() << std::endl;

    time_zone_ptr tz_utc(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("UTC"));
    std::cout << local_dt.local_time_in(tz_utc) << std::endl;
}
```

The same code on coliru is available by [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d72d528abeef00c) link.